# How to solve Selenium Web Driver Exception in Windows and Python?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I am trying to use selenium library in my python script.

I am using Windows 10 and I have downloaded the latest chrome driver required for selenium.

Although I have added the path till chromedriver.exe file in my system's PATH environment variable, yet I am getting following error-

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Chrome failed to start: was killed
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location E:/pg/chromedriver.exe is no 
longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 
(49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 
x86_64)
```

I searched this error in web and added chrome options arguments like below-

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-impl-side-painting")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-breakpad")
options.add_argument("--disable-client-side-phishing-detection")
options.add_argument("--disable-cast")
options.add_argument("--disable-cast-streaming-hw-encoding")
options.add_argument("--disable-cloud-import")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--disable-session-crashed-bubble")
options.add_argument("--disable-ipv6")
options.add_argument("--allow-http-screen-capture")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.binary_location = chrome_binary # chrome.exe
driver_binary = r"E:/pg/chromedriver.exe"
driver = wd.Chrome(driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
try:
    login(driver)
    followers = scrape_followers(driver, account)
    print(followers)
    following = scrape_following(driver, account)
    print(following)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

But it did not solve the error.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve my issue.
I removed the 'r' from the chrome driver path and also the all .add_argument() and now it's working fine.
So instead of using `driver_binary = r'E:\pg\chromedriver.exe'`
I am using `driver_binary = 'E:\pg\chromedriver.exe'`